# Prove that area of DEF = area of D'E'F'

Tags: geometry, triangles

Question -

If D,D'  E,E'  F,F' are isotomics pairs of points on side BC,CA,AB of ABC Prove that area of DEF = D'E'F'

My try -

Because they are isotomics they are equidistant from midpoint of corresponding sides..so I 
First try to prove that they are congruent but unable to do so ..any hints will be valuable..

Answer (score 0):

Hint:  Perform an affine transformation so that the triangle is equilateral.

Then the result follows since

$$ A( 1-B) + B ( 1 - C)  + C ( 1-A) = A ( 1-C) + B (1-A)+ C ( 1- B) $$

Comment: Is there a proof using Euclidean geometry

Comment: I consider affine transformations part of the set of tools of Euclidean geometry (and in your case, for IMO) . So, can you be more specific about what you are allowing / disallowing?

Comment: Actually I am doing problems from the book CTPCM and in that they did not teach what affine transformation is till now ...

Comment: What's the chapter that this problem is from? That might suggest how they would like to approach the problem. It likely could be done via brute force algebra, but I don't think that's the point.